# What is a Scientific approach to Law and Epistemology?

Tags: united-states, research-topic

[***In an extended discussion in Law SE chat***](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71158/discussion-on-answer-by-dale-m-why-12-jurors-why-not-11-10-9-1), there was a description of the legal approach to epistemology, ***[namely one that is dependent upon the findings of the various actors of the criminal justice system](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/25059/why-12-jurors-why-not-11-10-9-1/25061#25061)***: police, defendants and plaintiffs, judges, lawyers, and juries. The specific quote that I wanted to touch upon was:

> It means that science and law fundamentally (and, one could argue, incompatibly) disagree on the nature of truth. In science, no group exists that can declare something "fact". In law, that's what juries and/or judges do. Asking scientific questions about something science considers impossible is akin to asking what color the most magical unicorns are. - cHao

But despite this, I know that there is a distinct gap in my knowledge of both realms to conclusively address the issue.

> How would you test it? It is fundamental that juries decide what is fact from disputed evidence (juries have nothing to do when the parties agree what the facts are). How do you set up your double blind experiment when there is no way of telling objectively who the guilty and not guilty defendants are? - Dale M

Taking a research-approach to the question, I posited a rough sketch of how I would've approached the topic.

> @DaleM complete taking a guess here, a control (12 jurors) and different experimental groups consisting of different sizes. A known “case” where it is known with a p value of <0.05 that the defendant is X (can be real or imagined). The prosecution (study confederate) would present evidence systematically and equally to all groups but without knowing actual case X. Based on experimental results, determine optimal jury size. - Me

So I ask:

- Why is there a fundamental gap between law and science?
- Can the two ever be 'merged' or 'reconciled'?
- How would both realms work if they adopted attributes from either realm?

Comment: Perhaps religion can be the go-between...

Comment: Religion as in different belief systems, or as a legal/social construct i.e. a body of individuals consisting of an organization?

Comment: I disagree that scientists cannot declare something "fact." Do you have evidence to support this?

Answer (score 2):

Courts have to make a definite decision (that can only be appealed so often) about what the law is in every given case. The law reduces uncertainty.

Scientific progress builds on fallibility, at least in the empirical sciences. The final proof is always elusive, postponed indefinitely. And because every provisional answer invites new questions, science produces uncertainty.

Both systems can, fundamentally, not be reconciled, because they operate according to different logics.

Comment: What did you mean by uncertainty? I read it as the degree of which people can recognize that the decision was from a legitimate source.

Comment: What I mean is that the accused cannot be found guilty  with p <0.05. The judgement must be either/or.

Comment: Why couldn't you find someone guilty with P<0.5? In absent of experimental data, wouldn't the hypothesis not be rejected?

Comment: Because the notion of "guilty" in law is NOT "did the thing they were accused of" but rather "has to go to jail and or pay a fine".  You might be able to say someone killed someone else with p>.95, but a person cannot go to jail with p>.95; they either go to jail or not.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo I don’t think I got that right. The scope of the question is one’s confidence that someone is guilty or not. In absence of a “smoking gun” couldn’t everything be characterized as probability and confidence?

Comment: @FrankFYC - you didn't understand me.  There are two concepts here, legal-guilty and real-guilty.  Definition of legal-guilty: person is obliged to go to jail.  Definition of real-guilty: person actually did the crime they are charged with.  The point is that legal-guilty cannot have a p-value, even if real-guilty does.  At best, you might try to define legal-guilty as "real-guilty with p-value >0.95".  But, as you see, this already creates a divergence between the two concepts.

Answer (score 1):

I will describe a situation in legal practice and then say something about it.  This is a rather specialized area of the law.  It's the only one that I know a lot about.

When a parent of a special learner believes that his child's school district has not been playing according to Hoyle, i.e. has not been faithfully following IDEA 2004 ("The Individuals with Disabilities Education Act"), he may request an impartial hearing.

If he lives in a "two tier" state, such as New York, there is a fast, streamlined procedure for appealing the decision to the State Review Office (SRO).

The SRO appeal system functions somewhat as a way of auditing the hearing decisions.

One can make all kinds of statistical observations about the frequency with which the SRO has overturned hearing decisions.

This is an example of a scholarly approach to the law.  Someone who does this comprehensively and well is Perry Zirkel.  He also compares results and approaches from one state to another.  Perhaps it would be helpful for you to take a look at his [work](https://perryzirkel.com/publications/), so you can see what's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Law is based upon natural language which is inherently ambiguous, thus, reasoning is based upon personal interpretation and is indefinitive.

Science is rooted in logic which strives to be unambiguous, thus, reasoning is based upon agreed-up rules and is definitive.

Science would fail if it were reliant on natural language and personal interpretation. Law might-well become more definitive if it adopted attributes from science, but this will never happen. Partly because law cannot be codified in logic, at least, not yet. Partly because codification would require significant resources. Partly because the law functions, whereas any future system is untested; if it ain't broke, don't fix it. Partly because ...

Comment: "law cannot be codified in logic, at least, not yet." You need to state what you mean by law here, there are certainly many logics of norms, including legal norms. From the more philosophical side, the area and class of logics is called Deontic Logic (as in, you can have a deontic logic), elsewhere it's simply called normative or legal reasoning. Many modern deontic logics work very much like a jurist would understand the law modulo interpretation - an argument is made for a conclusion by applying rules and facts, all counter-arguments are sought, counter-counter-arguments, and so on.

Comment: This is touched upon by the following answer: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/102130/22768

Comment: That link is bizarre "maybe it's reasonable but it's not logic" is incorrect regarding contradiction in law. If a formalism lacks explosion then it cannot be classical logic, but it can be a non-classical logic such as non-monotonic logic (which bans contradiction) or, controversially, paraconsistent logic (which bans explosion). Many logics specifically handle law's contradictory nature. Hence, I think the answer needs some clarification. That aside, I'm not sure if (currently) lacking a formal logic makes something non-scientific, it just pushes it outside of formal science.

Comment: The claim "maybe it's reasonable but it's not logic" relates to a particular class of logic, which is distinct from the class of logic that you're referring to. A formal logic certainly isn't necessary and my answer is incredibly superficial. That said, I think it touches upon a key point: law is indefinitive; science is definitive. Of course, that's rather a sweeping claim and you can pick away at it. But, I'm posting to the Internet, whilst working, on the weekend; I'm not trying to compose a conclusive argument.

Answer (score -1):

US law appears to not accept standard logic and rejects [ex falso quodlibet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion) in particular. You cannot argue that

1. The US constitution demands separation of church and state
2. The Alabama constitution (or whatever) requires elected officials to be Christian

and therefore

3. My client is not guilty of this traffic violation.

Laws "in the books" that are in direct contradiction with higher laws cannot be challenged unless it's by an event directly related to them. Maybe that's reasonable but it's not logic.